# pixel by pixel conversion of Iplimage from RGB to gray

Tags: image

I am trying to convert the Iplimage from RGB to gray but after conversion the image looks so much noisy. Are there any way to get better image . Here is what i have done.

```
 void gray()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<image->width*image->height*image->nChannels;i+=image->nChannels) 
        {
            float b=abs(image->imageData[i]);
            float g=abs(image->imageData[i+1]);
            float r=abs(image->imageData[i+2]);
            float a=(float)(b+g+r)/3;
            //a=a/256;
           - if(a<0)
           {
               a=0;
        }
    image->imageData[i]=a;
    image->imageData[i+1]=a;
    image->imageData[i+2]=a;
   }
}
```

Comment: may add some input output ?

Comment: I have low reputation so that I could not upload images

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::cvarrToMat(image);
cv::Mat chan[3];
cv::split(m, chan);
m = (chan[0] + chan[1] + chan[2])/3.
```

P.S. not tested